# How to get an Innosetup installer package to display a non-scaled icon image (>32x32)

Tags: installation, icons, inno-setup, image-size

I've started using 'large' icons on my desktop. For a while I've also been including images > 32x32 in my Delphi Application. The result is a nice clean image display in all Windows display situtations. I know its rather picky, but i've just noticed that a compiled Innosetup package displays fuzzy - I presume its being scaled - and it occured to me that there must be a way of adding to or changing the default Innosetup image displayed for its EXE. You can see the effect in the image below. I have many icons available to me, so a solution for replacing the default icon would be great.

[image: Innosetup package versus other items]

Answer (score 4):

Ah I found it. To specify a custom icon for a setup application, use the [`SetupIconFile`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_setupiconfile) directive:

```
[Setup]
SetupIconFile="MyIcon.ico"
```

Comment: Some image editors (like GIMP) allows you to create icon (*.ico) with multiple layers. Each icon can be created with 16x16, 32x32, 48x48, 64x64 layers and so on. I think if such (multiple layers) icon is used Windows can pick optimal dimension.

Comment: @Slappy, lol, GIMP. The last time I've used it, I was wondering if its developers even tried to draw something with it. For me is GIMP the most user unfriendly application I've ever used. Functions are fine, but the GUI... If there would be some console mode of GIMP I would rather use it that way :-)

Comment: @Slappy Yes you are right about the picking of resolutions, that's why I wanted it :-) And as for GIMP, well, have you tried using it for anything other than basic operations? Its very daunting.